# Length of the longest decreasing subsequence built by appending elements to the end and the front using dynamic programming

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The restrictions are that the elements can be appended to the front if they are greater than the element at the front and to the back if they are smaller than the back. It can also ignore elements (and there comes the difficulty).

Example:

Input:
`{6, 7, 3, 5, 4}`

The longest sequence to that input is:

- Start with `{6}`.
- Append 7 to the front because it is greater than 6. `{7, 6}`
- Ignore 3.
- Append 5 to the back because it is smaller. `{7, 6, 5}`
- Append 4 to the back because it is smaller. `{7, 6, 5, 4}`

If we appended 3, the sequence would be smaller `{7, 6, 3}` because then we wouldn't be able to append 4.

I tried to adapt a LIS algorithm to solve it, but the results are totally wrong.

```
int adapted_LIS(int input[], int n)
{
    int score[n] = {};
    score[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        score[i] = 1;
        int front = input[i];
        int back = input[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (input[j] > front)
            {
                front = input[j];
                score[i] = std::max(score[i], score[j] + 1);
            }
            else if (input[j] < back)
            {
                back = input[j];
                score[i] = std::max(score[i], score[j] + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return *std::max_element(score, score + n);
}
```

How can I solve it using Dynamic Programming?

Comment: `int score[n] = {};` is not standard C++. Whats your question?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I want to know if I am adapting it wrong or if I need to use another algorithm.

Comment: ".. but the results are totally wrong." you already know that it isnt correct , now you should use a debugger to see where the code differs from what you expect it to do

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I wonder if I just got a bad implementation or if it is not possible to solve using that algorithm.

Comment: Is this truly a dynamic programming problem? A dynamic programming problem's optimal solution involves finding solutions to overlapping sub-problems,  emphasis on the word *overlapping*. My understanding of *overlapping* is that in solving for the optimal solution, the same sub-problems come up  (e.g. computing Fibonacci numbers recursively), which is not the case here. See [this soluton](https://ideone.com/ftpmne), which happens to be in Python., but you just have to read the comments and the output. Or is there a more optimal solution that does use memoization for recurring sub-problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The optimal substructure that we need for dynamic programming is that, given two sequences with the same front and back, it’s obviously better to extend the longer one (or the same, if the sequences have the same length). Here’s some C++. It’s inefficient for clarity and so that it can’t be fed directly to an online judge, but there’s a straightforward path to O(n³). With a little data structural cleverness, O(n² log n).

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> PushFront(int x, std::vector<int> subsequence) {
  subsequence.insert(subsequence.begin(), x);
  return subsequence;
}

std::vector<int> PushBack(std::vector<int> subsequence, int x) {
  subsequence.push_back(x);
  return subsequence;
}

void Consider(std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>> &table,
              std::vector<int> subsequence) {
  std::vector<int> &entry = table[{subsequence.front(), subsequence.back()}];
  if (subsequence.size() > entry.size()) {
    entry = std::move(subsequence);
  }
}

std::vector<int> TwoSidedDecreasingSubsequence(const std::vector<int> &input) {
  if (input.empty()) {
    return {};
  }
  // Maps {front, back} to the longest known subsequence.
  std::map<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>> table;
  for (int x : input) {
    auto table_copy = table;
    for (const auto &[front_back, subsequence] : table_copy) {
      auto [front, back] = front_back;
      if (x > front) {
        Consider(table, PushFront(x, subsequence));
      }
      if (back > x) {
        Consider(table, PushBack(subsequence, x));
      }
    }
    Consider(table, {x});
  }
  return std::max_element(
             table.begin(), table.end(),
             [&](const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>> &a,
                 const std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<int>> &b) {
               return a.second.size() < b.second.size();
             })
      ->second;
}

int main() {
  for (int x : TwoSidedDecreasingSubsequence({6, 7, 3, 5, 4})) {
    std::cout << ' ' << x;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid copying the table n times?

Comment: @GabrielHenrique If you switch to a 2D array indexed by input indices instead of input values, you can modify the loop to iterate over only the existing part of the table.